# how to send individual data fields from logstash to zabbix

Tags: zabbix, logstash

so we want to monitor the Tomcat access times with zabbix. I looked at logstash, thinking that it could parse the log messages, and it can. I get parts of the log message as individual fields in the verbose logstash output. so far so good.

now for the zabbix_sender plugin. and this is where it goes wrong: following the example from the logstash website, I have managed to send the whole logmessage to the zabbix server alright. But how can I tell logstash to send only the access time?

Below is an example with a mysql log filter which I used for playing around:

```
filter {
   grok {
     type => "mysql-log"
     match => [ "message", "%{NUMBER:date} %{TIME:time} %{DATA:themessage}" ]
     add_tag => [ "zabbix-sender" ]
     add_field => [
       "zabbix_host", "my-host",
       "zabbix_item", "my-key"
     ]
  }
}
```

what do I need to change to only send the message in this example?

**[EDIT]**

looking at the logstash code for the zabbix plugin, I'd say I'm out of luck here, but maybe someone knows some workaround? I don't want to have to deal with rolling logs myself...